# What is thread dump and heap dump in jmeter and how can we generate and analyse the thread dump

Tags: jmeter

I'm using JMeter for load testing, how can I analyze the thread and heap dumps for the load test.
I'm on JMeter 5.1.1 version, under tools there are 2 options like create heap dump and create thread dump, what is the actual usage of them and how could we analyze the dump files.
using which tool we can analyse the dump files

Answer (score 0):

**Thread dump** is a **snapshot** of the state of all threads that are part of the process. The state of each thread is presented with a so called stack trace, which shows the contents of a thread's stack. Some of the threads belong to the Java application you are running, while others are JVM internal threads
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/using_threaddumps.html

A **heap dump** is a **snapshot** of the memory of a Java™ process. The snapshot contains information about the Java objects and classes in the heap at the moment the snapshot is triggered. Because there are different formats for persisting this data, there might be some differences in the information provided.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS3KLZ/com.ibm.java.diagnostics.memory.analyzer.doc/heapdump.html

https://dzone.com/articles/java-heap-dump-analyzer-1

You can search for various tools to analyse thread dump(https://fastthread.io/) and heap dump(https://www.yourkit.com/)

Hope this helps.